# email id is shown in red color on passing parameters as post in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, http-post

I am trying to run a recorded script by passing different csv values for email id. On the POST request for email it is showing me as red and my script is getting failed

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer solution,  On the POST request I encoded my email ID and passed the parameters as multi form data and disabled the embedded resource download from Jmeter properties which was throwing an error on the POST request.